# 'Checkout' or 'copy' the new repo dir into the working copy?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I created a directory in a repo directory, which I have a working copy for. My working copy is locally changed, and an update doesn't pull the new folder into the working copy, giving no errors.

Should I 'copy' the related folder into its place in the WC, or should I make a 'checkout'?

Will a checkout of a subdir into a working copy work as if it was done with the initial checkout in the beginning? Or would it result in a more complex working copy (like two nested working copy structures, an additional .svn folder or something)

Using tortoise svn, 1.7+

Comment: You are pretty vague in your description (what does "created a directory in a repo folder" mean exactly?), use weird terms (dirty working copy) and suggest you are getting errors ("update won't bring the new folder") without further details. If you see you get no answer, you can edit your question and try to be more clear.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Sorry, I tried to be as clear as I could. I created a directory in a 'repo directory which I have a working copy for'. 'Dirty' meaned 'locally changed' and not submitted. Update just didn't 'pull' the folder which was created in the repo, no errors, so couldn't find any more details to give -) Thanks anyway for the reminder, revised the question a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried specifically doing an `svn up <folder>` in the working copy rather than a generic `svn up`?  If your local working copy is dirty and you don't need the changes you could just `svn revert .`.  Otherwise just move the existing working copy out of the way, check out a new version, and copy over what you need, and move on.

Comment: thank you barry. seems it was related to the working copy depth. the 'checkout to the revision..' dialog has option to choose items, I used it with head rev. and the WC is updated with the new folder.

Comment: No problem.  svn gets itself into a mess quite easily unfortunately.  Source code control shouldn't be a hinderence :)